# Is this the correct way to check if an element exists in an array?

Tags: jquery, arrays, validation

Is this the correct way of checking to see that a selected file type matches an allowed file type in Jquery?

```
var selectedFiles = $('#add_post_file');
var allowedFiles = ['image/jpg','image/gif','image/png'];
var goodFiles = 0;
var numFiles = $('#add_post_file').get(0).files.length;     
for(var i = 0; i < numFiles; i++){              
    var file = $('#add_post_file').files[i];
    if(jQuery.inArray(selectedFiles.get(0).files[i].type, allowedFiles) > -1){
        goodFiles++;
    };
    i++;
};                      
if(goodFiles == numFiles){
    alert('good');
    // continue
}
else{
    alert('one or more files were incorrect file types.');
};
```

Thanks

Comment: What does `selectedFiles.get(0).files[i].type` return

Comment: image/png is what is returned.

Answer (score 1):

Can be simplified as

```
for(var i = 0; i < numFiles; i++){

   var file = selectedFiles.files[i];
   if(jQuery.inArray(file.type, allowedFiles) > -1){
        goodFiles++;
    }
}
```

You also need not increment the vale of `i` . It will be taken care of in the for loop